# Past Tense of Break Bread

Tags: past-tense, obscure-terms

According to this site (https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Break%20bread), to "break bread" means to engage in amiable conversation. However, I cannot find a sufficiently reliable source for its past tense. For example, would the sentence, "We broke bread on our first date," be correct?

Comment: I think your example is okay grammatically, but not necessarily the clearest way of describing what happened on a date.

Comment: Breaking bread means sharing a meal. Past tense is broke bread.

Comment: It would be rather odd to use the phrase when speaking of a date. It usually refers to a Christian communion service, or to a meal taken by a group of friends (Oxford calls the latter usage 'dated').

Comment: @user10121076 "*would the sentence, "We broke bread on our first date,*" be correct?" No. It is not idiomatic at all: it is very old fashioned and stilted ... and it sounds weird. My advice is to not use "to break bread."